# Rails 5 client_side_validation not working on modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using gem 'client_side_validations'
and gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form' and all validation  WORKS FINE IN A NORMAL FORM, but not working when try to adapt in a bootstrap modal, this is my form in modal:

```
<div class="modal-content" id="modal_usuario">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

</div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <%= simple_form_for(@usuario, html: {class: "miform form-horizontal"}, validate: true) do |f| %>
 <h4>Nuevo Usuario</h4>
 <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :usuario, class: "col-sm-4" %>
    <%= f.text_field :usuario, class: "col-sm-5" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password, class: "col-sm-4" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: "col-sm-5" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmar contraseña", class: "col-sm-4" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "col-sm-5" %>
</div>
--- some extra code---
```

and this is my new.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= j (render partial: 'new' ) %>");
```

so the modal is shown correctly but the client side validation are not working, i read the documentation of this gem and show this solution:
https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/wiki/Bootstrap-Modal-Validations

```
$(document).on 'shown.bs.modal', '.modal', ->
  $('form[data-client-side-validations]').enableClientSideValidations()
```

but i dont know where add this code and i would like to add it in js not in coffe. Can someone show me how to translate this code to js and in which folder or file should i add this code? or if you have other solution. thanks

im using: gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.3',

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'

Answer (score 0):

Within your `app/assets/javascript/application.js` you likely `require_tree .` which means that if you create a new file called something like `boostrap_client_side_val.js` you could simply paste in this and it should work.

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('form[data-client-side-validations]').enableClientSideValidations();
}).modal('show');
```

Comment: I add the code in app/assets/javascript/application.js, but not results yet, if I am using turbolinks it will work?or should i change something else?

Comment: You might need to wrap it in `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { CODEHERE })`

Comment: should write inside $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function() { ... ? if it is already inside of $(document).on...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but maybe this will save someone some heartache. By default, this gem only enables/validates VISIBLE forms so modals and tabs are a pain since they are not visible until the events shown.bs.modal and shown.bs.tab are fired (which is after your JS would typically run). After several iterations of fiddling with binding, I found this to be the easiest solution...just overwrite the gem's selectors so that it WILL enable and validate hidden forms.

```
// my-client-side-validations-initializer.js

window.ClientSideValidations.selectors = {
    inputs: ':input:not(button):not([type="submit"])[name]:enabled',
    validate_inputs: ':input:enabled[data-validate]',
    forms: 'form[data-client-side-validations]'
}
```